# Saving login session state with Instagram OAuth

Tags: php, cookies, oauth, server-side, instagram

Currently I have a page with a link to OAuth using Instagram. If the login is successful, I am redirected back to the same php page with the user's information. However, if I refresh the page, the user will see the login link again (it's hidden when the user is logged in). I know I should use cookies to save state information, but what should I store in the cookie? If I store the username (only returned with a successful login), would that be unsecure since anyone can modify the cookie on their own computer with any other username and gain access to their account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the server side authentication flow, your callback page should receive an access_token in the url, so:

1. Send users to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code` with your apps credentials (client id, and redirect uri)... make sure your response type is `code`. If the user says no, they are redirected to your uri with the `error` parameter
2. When the user authenticates your app, they will be redirected to your redirect uri with the `code` parameter `http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE`
3. Now you can get the access token, this is what you should store in a cookie. Send a `POST` request from your backend (using cURL or similar in PHP) off to instagram asking for the token with the parameters `code`, `redirect_uri`, 'grant_type=authorization_code', and your `client_secret`

Source: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/